# How can I clean up my code for my nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to make a nested dictionary with user input. The user is asked to input a name, age and shoe size. Each set of these inputs will be stored in separate dictionaries

Any tips to clean up my code? I'm a beginner btw, so I would appreciate it if the solutions provided were somewhat basic/simple

my code:

```
info = {
1: {'Name': "",
       "Age": 0, "Shoe size": 0},

2: {'Name': "",
       "Age": 0, "Shoe size": 0},

3: {'Name': "",
       "Age": 0, "Shoe size": 0},

4: {'Name': "",
       "Age": 0, "Shoe size": 0}
}

for i in range(1):
    x = input("Enter a name: ")
    info[1]["Name"] = (x)
    y = int(input("Enter their age: "))
    info[1]["Age"] = (y)
    z = int(input("Enter their shoe size: "))
    info[1]["Shoe size"] = (z)
    print()

    x = input("Enter a name: ")
    info[2]["Name"] = (x)
    y = int(input("Enter their age: "))
    info[2]["Age"] = (y)
    z = int(input("Enter their shoe size: "))
    info[2]["Shoe size"] = (z)
    print()

    x = input("Enter a name: ")
    info[3]["Name"] = (x)
    y = int(input("Enter their age: "))
    info[3]["Age"] = (y)
    z = int(input("Enter their shoe size: "))
    info[3]["Shoe size"] = (z)
    print()

    x = input("Enter a name: ")
    info[4]["Name"] = (x)
    y = int(input("Enter their age: "))
    info[4]["Age"] = (y)
    z = int(input("Enter their shoe size: "))
    info[4]["Shoe size"] = (z)
    print()

for p_id, p_info in info.items():
    print("\nPerson:", p_id)

    for key in p_info:
        print(key + ':', p_info[key])
```

Comment: Use functions for repeating code

Comment: You may want to ask this on [codereview.se] instead.

Answer (score 2):

Don't needlessly prefill `info` with dummy data and give the loop some actual purpose

```
info = {}

for i in range(1, 5):
    info[i] = {}
    info[i]["Name"] = input("Enter a name: ")
    info[i]["Age"] = int(input("Enter their age: "))
    info[i]["Shoe size"] = int(input("Enter their shoe size: "))
    print()
```

by iterating more than once and using the loop variable for the changing part of the repeating code.